# What is the value of OPEN_EXISTING in the Windows API?

Tags: winapi

What is the value of OPEN_EXISTING in the Windows API?

I'm trying to open directories directly so I can examine the entries for deleted files, and I need to specify that value, but the C# environment doesn't include that under the FileMode enumeration.

related question: [CreateFile to view a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344094)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the value of OPEN_EXISTING is 3.

[MSDN - CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

General tip: Download the Windows SDK, no matter what language you are using. Then you can grep the included header files and look for the constants.