# C# - Reading free space bits on harddrive

Tags: c#, hard-drive, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I undelete a file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352550/how-can-i-undelete-a-file-using-c)

Ever since I recovered a document using a software called Undelete, that scans your free space and shows you what files are recoverable, I was curious on how to program this. Being a new programmer where would I look to begin to research this?

From an article:

When you search for a particular file that has been deleted, the Undelete software scans the hard drive for pointers that were deleted recently. It then uses these pointers to locate the exact location of the deleted file. Once it locates the deleted data, it just recovers the data using the information available. Once the file has been recovered completely, you can now access it like before.

How would I begin this with C#?

Comment: This is exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1352550/608772

Comment: My mistake for not finding it with search. Here is the code in C++ for other interested readers. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/NTFSUndelete.aspx