# How to read the contents of an entire disk bit by bit

Tags: c#, c++

I've got a flash card that I need to compute a checksum on the entire contents of the drive.

If I could acquire a stream to the entire drive I could just read it in bit by bit.

Does anyone know if there is an API for doing this?

Everything I see so far requires me to open a file.

Is there any way to just read an entire drive's contents bit by bit?

Comment: You can do this using WMI.. are you familiar with WMI

Answer (score 11):

If you want to write C# code, then you'll have to use P/Invoke to read data from your disk (RAW access).

> Is there any way to just read an entire drive's contents bit by bit?

You'll have to make a difference between the **drive** (**logical** representation of your flash card, with a FileSystem installed on it, specified by **the drive letter**) and the **disk** (**physical** representation of your flash card, specified by **the disk number**).

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820157/870604) about how to read RAW data from a drive/disk:

Basically, you'll first need a handle to the disk/drive:

```
// For a DISK:
IntPtr hDisk = CreateFile(string.Format("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive{0}", diskNumber),
    GenericRead,
    Read | Write,
    0,
    OpenExisting,
    0,
    IntPtr.Zero);

// For a DRIVE
IntPtr hDrive = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
    string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}:", DriveLetter)
    GenericRead,
    Read | Write,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    OpenExisting,
    0,
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then use `SetFilePointerEx` (so you can move the offset where you want to read), `ReadFile` (fills a buffer with bytes read from the disk/drive), `CloseHandle` (closes the handle opened by CreateFile).

Read the disk/drive by chunks (so basically, a loop from offset "0" to offset "disk/drive size").

What's important (or `ReadFile` will always fail): the **size of read chunks must be a multiple of the sector size of your disk** (512 bytes generally).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if there is direct support for this in `.NET`, but you can use [Platform Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) to call the Win32 API functions.  [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) should be your starting point, as it allows you to get a handle to the physical drive:

> You can use the CreateFile function to open a physical disk drive or a volume, which
>   returns a direct access storage device (DASD) handle that can be used with the 
>   DeviceIoControl function. This enables you to access the disk or volume directly, for
>   example such disk metadata as the partition table.

The documentation informs you of restrictions (such as requiring administrative privileges) and hints at how to get a physical drive number from the volume letter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Stream" is an abstraction that *normally* assumes the presence of a file system, so conceptually it's not quite as simple as that.

On Windows, you might want to start by looking at the Windows Defragmentation API. Here are a couple of links I found:

- [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Defrag API C# wrappers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx)

Comment: Actually, the whole point of the `stream` abstraction is that it does _not_ assume a file system. You can treat in-memory streams, file streams, and serial ports all the same. And if the OS lets you, an entire disk.