# Calculating checksum of a flash drive's contents

Tags: c#, c++, c

I'm looking for a good way of calculating a checksum of an entire flash drive's contents.

Not a particular file, or a group of files, but the entire volume which is read only so it never changes.

Does anyone know of any C, C++, or C# code that can open a flash drive volume and read it byte for byte efficiently so I can feed this to say an MD5 or SHA1 hash algorithm?

I see lots of code for now to read files but I'd like to read the entire physical drive from beginning to end.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. Flash memory has limited life (in terms of number of reads/writes); you don't want to do a frequent heavy IO operation like this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ashes999: Only writes wear flash memory.  The potential number of reads is practically unlimited.

Comment: @BenVoigt are you sure? I guess I'm mistaken then; that's good to know.

Comment: Any particular reason you did not find answers to your original question useful? possible duplicate of [How to read the contents of an entire disk bit by bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417557/how-to-read-the-contents-of-an-entire-disk-bit-by-bit)

Answer (score 2):

You can open a whole volume using the OS-level file APIs (C# suggests Windows, where the function is `CreateFile`).

You should probably unmount the filesystem first, however, lest some other process change your data while you're using it.  Also, a checksum of the entire volume is not likely to be useful, since it'll change whenever the "last accessed time" field gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at the source code for [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) and the [SHA-1](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html) functions in OpenSSL.