# Backup Hard Drive and USB Device to img or iso file

Tags: c#, backup, usb-drive

I seek a way to copy the raw data.
Specifically, I seek a way to clone a removable disk, and another hard drive to an image file (ISO, IMG, ...), so you can re-use on another computer through appropriate software.

Do you know a way to perform this action.

Comment: Did a quick search for ya: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can use `isoburn.exe` to burn images from the command line (at least in Win7):

```
isoburn.exe /q "{drive letter}:\{path to image file}"
```

Now all you have to do is create a new `Process` from your C# app and run the above code.

Comment: I left your principle and I used DSFO.exe. This command line utility makes a copy of the raw data and the image file can be used by all tools that allow reading raw image (HDDGURU Raw Copy Tool for example).

Answer (score 3):

As you added `C#` tag, I assume you want to do this by writing some code.

What you could do is to read the disk (RAW access), sector by sector, and copy all those bytes into a file that has the `*.iso` extension. An ISO image is only a copy of every written sector of a disk.

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417737/870604) that explains how to read (RAW access) a disk or drive.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DiskUtils](http://discutils.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.  From the site:
DiscUtils is a .NET library to read and write ISO files and Virtual Machine disk files (VHD, VDI, XVA, VMDK, etc). DiscUtils is developed in C# with no native code (or P/Invoke).

Answer (score 0):

PowerIso would work just fine if i understand the need