# c# File.Delete recovery?

Tags: c#, file, recovery

Is there a way to recover file(s) that have been deleted programatically by the `File.Delete()` method?

Deleted files do not appear in the recycle bin.

Comment: You might be lucky using a file system recovery tool. Otherwise you might only be lucky if you have a backup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. `File.Delete()` calls a hard delete within the API and by-passes the Recycle Bin. You will need to use a file recovery program and hope for the best.

For deletion via the Recycle Bin you use the `SHFileOperation` API as it is part of the shell.

If/once you have your files back you might want to take a look at this SO answer which discusses changing `File.Delete()` to something that uses the Recycle Bin:

[Send a File to the Recycle Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin)

Comment: It's always been one of my frustrations that there's no corresponding method in the file namespace, ex. File.Recycle for this operation. Resorting to unmanaged code or VisualBasic's namespace always seemed like a bad compromise.

Answer (score 3):

No, directly there is no way to recover it.

You can use a recovery program or API to get your files.

If the files are important I would shutdown the computer right away.

Take a look at this: [C# classes to undelete files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819188/c-sharp-classes-to-undelete-files)

Same problem with answer.